# Magento variable for access token

Tags: magento2, variables, token, magento2-cloud

currently I have hardcoded my `API token` in my controller, Need to make it configurable so that it can be configured when the code is deployed in production.

So how can I store it on Magento variable from Magento cloud environment?

I see the variables section in `configure environment` in `https://us-3.magento.cloud`

If I set my customer variable there, then how can I access it in my controller file.

And what's with so many variables types in Magento and which should i use.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/env/variables-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Magento has talked about all environment variables in the link whichever you have shared.

I hope, you want to save the API token and fetch it on controller to trigger web service call right. If so, you can create simple store configuration option in your module system.xml file which will allow store admin to set the token whenever you want and you can easily change also without doing any deployment and all.

Comment: How to do it can you elaborate ?

Comment: I agree with @thamo

Also, you can add a variable with `env:` prefix on the Magento Cloud.

For example: `env:CONFIG__DEFAULT__GENERAL__STORE_INFORMATION__NAME = MY STORE`

This variable will rewrite configuration from the Admin Panel and lock it, so you cannot change it via the Admin Panel.

Comment: @summu - BaDos has shared the more relevant way. As you are using cloud env , please use env variable for keeping the token.